# I can't store data from setBackgroundMessageHandler

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase for pushing notification. When I get the notification in the background, I get data. I want to save this data in the local storage, but I get  this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setItem' of undefined

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-messaging.js');
firebase.initializeApp({
  messagingSenderId: '628214501041'
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  var notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
  };
  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
  var pushData = event.data.json();
  try {
    if(self.window.localStorage){
      self.localStorage.setItem('notificationData' , JSON.stringify(pushData) ) ;
    // }
  }
 catch (err) {
    console.log('Push error happened:', err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `self.window.localStorage.setItem` since that’s what you’re checking for in the if statement before.

Comment: Is this your service worker?

Comment: Is it possible for you to move to the latest FCM SDK? You are using pretty old version (there are many bugs in the previous versions)

Answer (score 1):

The `self` variable you're using in your code is not something that is defined by default.

But from your code, you're probably looking for:

```
if(self.window.localStorage) {
  self.window.localStorage.setItem('notificationData' , JSON.stringify(pushData) ) ;
}
```

So the change there is using `self.window.localStorage`, instead of `self.localStorage` in the second line.

Comment: in this case i have no error log but i don't get any response

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't access the local storage or the session storage from your service worker because it have no access to the DOM.

You should use [CacheAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache)

Or for persisting data and access it from your service worker and window instance use:

[IndexedDB](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/live-data-in-the-service-worker)

This is in the lifecyle of your service worker and can also be accessed by the window object.

Comment: Let me give you an example ,I din't Understand

Comment: Fetching data in the background is realized by service workers. They are between the browser and the network. By security reasons the service worker can't access the local sorage directly and you get an `undefind` object. I recommend to read this: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa.

Comment: so i should use worker.postMessage ()  for pass data to components ?

Comment: I have adjusted my answer to match your use-case.

Comment: If I want to use the notification information, what should I do outside the service worker?

Comment: I try to understand what you are want to do with stored data.

Comment: Think I want to console.log() this stored data in another component .

Comment: Are you using angularfire2?

Comment: Anyway. If you just want to persist some data and access it from your application you can use the IndexedDB. This is accessible from your service worker and your window interface.